# QT CMarkUp(XMLParser) error . iconv.h: no such file or director

Tags: c++, xml, qt, visual-c++, markup

[image]Hi All,
I have stuck in an error for a long time and cant figure out what it is . I am using CMarkup class (xml Parser) for parsing XML files which works perfectly in VC++ . When I move that into QT it started throwing some strange error which is hard for me to fix.It says

```
iconv.h: no such file or director
expected; before cd , etc.
```

I checked the CMArkup website where it says

> The MARKUP_ICONV mode is currently
>   automatically selected in g++ based 
>   on the **GNUC** predefined macro.
>   Again, you can turn off iconv usage 
>   by adding MARKUP_STDCONV to your
>   project preprocessor definitions, or 
>   on the command line with
>   -DMARKUP_STDCONV.
>   g++ main.cpp Markup.cpp MarkupTest.cpp -DMARKUP_STDCONV

I tried everything but still probem exist. Have anyone got into similar problem who can help me fixing this .

Comment: I am currently using Windows :)

Comment: To clarify: the image shows the iconv.h problem solved by defining MARKUP_WINCONV, but still having the fseeko and swprintf problems which can be solved with the #if defined changes in your comment below. Thanks for following up. Note: CMarkup 11.5+ won't require these workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add the definition to your Qt project, add this line to your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -DMARKUP_STDCONV
```

Comment: thanks for your answer .I used Markup_winconv which solved that error .But they   throws some additional errors like the one showed above in Markup. Attached a screen shot to the question .Do u have any idea

Comment: ANSWER TO OTHER ERRORS : The fseeko and ftello might be solved by changing Markup.h:218 to
#if defined(__GNUC_ZNIX__)
so that it will actually define MCD_FSEEK as fseek etc. For the swprintf problem, find the following in Markup.h:

#if defined(__GNUC__)
#define MCD_SSZ(sz) sz,(sizeof(sz)/sizeof(MCD_CHAR))

And change the __GNUC__ to __GNUC_ZNIX__ as follows:

#if defined(__GNUC_ZNIX__)
#define MCD_SSZ(sz) sz,(sizeof(sz)/sizeof(MCD_CHAR))